# hide element on load page and show it onclick

Tags: javascript, html

hello i'm using javascript to show and hide element. its working but when loading the page the element still visible until i click on the button then it will be hiding. in my case i need the opposite ( the element should not be visible on loading page until i click on the button)
this is my code :

```
<input type='button' id='hideshow' value='Sélectionnez la quantité'>
<div class="price-rules-table-wrapper">test test </div>
```

```
(function($){


$(document).ready(function(){
$('#hideshow').click(function(){
    $('.price-rules-table-wrapper').toggle('show');
  });
});


})(jQuery);
```

did i miss something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `display:none`:

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hideshow').click(function() {
      $('.price-rules-table-wrapper').toggle('show');
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' id='hideshow' value='Sélectionnez la quantité'>
<div class="price-rules-table-wrapper">test test </div>
```

Alternatively you can hide it programmatically on page load:

```js
 $('.price-rules-table-wrapper').hide();
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hideshow').click(function() {
      $('.price-rules-table-wrapper').toggle('show');
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' id='hideshow' value='Sélectionnez la quantité'>
<div class="price-rules-table-wrapper">test test </div>
```

Comment: @omayma Glad to help :)